# how to allow admin and customer to login in at same place but direct to other page after click button?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication

i have 2 textbox for name and password and a button

there 2 table, one admin and one customer

after i enter the customer name and password , it verify whether empty or incorrect password , if correct it will go to the customer page

however if i enter admin name and password and after verify it should go to the admin page

i am only able to allow use one table for the login ? so how should i change the code below?

```
Protected Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text) Then
        Failure.Text = "Invalid User Name and Password. Try Again."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MYdatabase").ConnectionString
    Dim myConn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
           Dim cmd = "Select * From Customer  where name = @name"
           Dim my As New SqlCommand(cmd, myConn)

    my.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text)
    Dim objReader As SqlDataReader


    myConn.Open()
    objReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

    FailureText.Text = " "

    If objReader.Read() Then
        Dim pass As String = objReader.GetString(2)
        Dim cusId As Integer = objReader.GetValue(0)

        If pass = txtPassword.Text Then
            Failure.Text = "Login Successful"
            Session("name") = txtName.Text
            Session("Password") = txtPassword.Text
            Session("customerID") = cusId

            my.Dispose()
            myConn.Dispose()
            Response.Redirect("CustomerHome.aspx")


        Else
            FailureText.Text = "Invalid Password"



        End If
    Else
        FailureText.Text = "Login Name does not exist"

    End If




End Sub
```

Comment: use role based authentication

Comment: @Neha i not sure how to use that, i was to use my way how am i goin to continue on?

Comment: One thing I noticed btw is that you don't close your connection if the user is invalid. I would use a using statement so the connection is always closed.

Comment: @devilking put a column rolename in your table and in your select query get the role name and on successful authentication check if it is admin then redirect to admin else to your customer page

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat the same process that you use to validate if the user is a customer, for validating if it's an administrator.

Where you put: `FailureText.Text = "Login Name does not exist"` you can repeat the code from above and first validate if the supplied username and password map to an administrator. If so, set the session for an Admin and redirect to the admin page. If not, show the failure text.

To make sure your code stays readable, I would split the validate function into multiple functions that are called from the main function(refactoring). So you would get functions like: `IsValidCustomer` and `IsValidAdministrator` that do there checking.